# WidgetPreviewContext is not working in a framework

Tags: ios, swiftui, macos-catalina, xcode12, widgetkit

I made a widget using new and shiny [WidgetKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit). It looks good and working as expected. Then I put all its logic into separate framework to share constant values between extension and main app as well as to provide a unit-testable target. And after introducing a framework SwiftUI previews stopped working. I'm getting error: `Cannot preview in this file - Could not find host for previews`. It seems that [WidgetPreviewContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetpreviewcontext) is not working. I'm wondering why. Could it be because I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.6?

Comment: What are the "Diagnostics"?

Comment: If it's the same error as me then diagnostics are as below. Did you have any luck @Artem ? ```"UnableToFindPreviewHostError<XcodeGraphSource>: Could not find host for previews

Could not find a host (app, extension, framework) given the open files and active `PreviewProvider` types. Make sure the open files and `PreviewProvider` types are target in the active scheme."```

Comment: @MichaC. Sorry for delay. Yeah, Neillnglis mentioned the same diagnostics as I have. So far, I haven't got any further with it.

Comment: Are you directly preview your YourWidget under preview? Instead preview the widget's main view. Also preview doesn't work on macOS, works only for iOS

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this because I guess some of the files I had open in the workspace wasn't part of the same target?

Anyways I fixed this error by closing all files I had open in Xcode except the SwiftUI Code.